# Laravel database optimization

Tags: php, mysql, performance, laravel

I have a code which fetches data from external API and commits it to DB afterwards:

```
protected function saveWidgetsToDatabase($widgetsDaily, Boost $boost, $date)
{
    echo "Saving widgets to DB... ";

    $widgets = Widget::all();
    foreach ($widgetsDaily as $widgetDaily) {
        $existingWidget = $widgets
            ->where('widget_id', $widgetDaily->id)
            ->where('date', $date)
            ->first();

        if ($existingWidget === null)
            $boost->widgets()->save(new Widget([
               ...
            ]));
        else
            $existingWidget->update([
                ...
            ]);
    }
}
```

Relation I have is that one `Boost` has many `Widgets`. Now, the issue I'm facing is bottleneck DB saving/updating as I need to update a widget only if it has same date and ID, otherwise I need to create new one.

We are talking about few thousands of records, so I believe that `where` clauses are pretty intensive.

I wanted to make a batch save, though I didn't quite make it.

Are there any chances of making this faster?

Comment: Do you have `widget_id` and `date` indexed?

Comment: No, not really...would that help?

Comment: Yes. Indexing helps the database find information faster, and would speed up your `where` queries.

Comment: Please provide the generated SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `Widget::all();`, that gets every single widget record in your database and creates a `Widget` instance for it. Therefore, `$widgets` will be a `Collection` of every `Widget` object stored in the database. If you have 10000 widget records, you'll have a `Collection` of 10000 `Widget` objects. This is obviously not what you want.

That also means that when you call `$widgets->where()...`, you're calling `where()` on the `Collection` object, which is using PHP to filter through the collection of objects, instead of using SQL to filter the database results.

There are a couple things you can do.

First, you know you only care about those widgets that have an id in the list of `$widgetsDaily`. So, limit your `Widget` query to only include those records that have a `widget_id` in that list of ids.

Second, add the date lookup to the database query as well.

Third, key the resulting collection by the `widget_id` field, so that you can directly access the item by the `widget_id` without having to loop through the entire collection looking for it every time.

```
protected function saveWidgetsToDatabase($widgetsDaily, Boost $boost, $date)
{
    // Get the only widget_ids we care about (assumes $widgetsDaily is a collection)
    $ids = $widgetsDaily->pluck('id')->all();

    // Get the target widgets from the database. This collection will only
    // contain widgets that we actually care about.
    $widgets = Widget::whereIn('widget_id', $ids)
        ->where('date', $date)
        ->get()
        ->keyBy('widget_id'); // rekey the resulting collection

    foreach ($widgetsDaily as $widgetDaily) {
        // Because the collection was rekeyed on widget_id, you can use
        // get(id) instead of having to use where('widget_id', id)->first()
        $existingWidget = $widgets->get($widgetDaily->id);

        if ($existingWidget === null)
            $boost->widgets()->save(new Widget([
               ...
            ]));
        else
            $existingWidget->update([
                ...
            ]);
    }
}
```